# Basic questions on Ideal generated by a set.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Firstly Please correct me ,if i am assuming something wrong.

Let $(R,+,.)$ be a commutative ring ,not necessearily unital. Then
$I\subset R$ is Ideal if $I$ has following properties,
$(I,+) < (R,+)$ and
$\forall x\in I,r\in R \implies rx\in I$

My question is ,by defination ideals generated by say $1$ elements ,is given by

$$(a)=\{ar \mid \forall r\in R \}$$

How does $a\in (a)$ ,if we not assume unity ?
$a\in (a)\implies a=a.r$ for some $r\in R$

Similarly for $2$ elements say ,$$(a,b)=\{ar+bs \mid \forall r,s\in R \}$$

How does $a+b$ belongs to this ?
As this will lead to ,$a+b=ar+bs$ ! As ideals are also additive subgroup ,these all should belongs to $I$ ! Where am i making mistake ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expresion of $(a)=\{ar\;|\;\forall r\in R\}$ is a consecuence of the definition of *ideal generated by a set*. The deffinition is:
\begin{equation}
(a)=\bigcap_{\substack{(I,+)<(R,+)\\
 a\in (I,+)}} I
\end{equation}
Or in general, for a set $A\subseteq R$
\begin{equation}
(A)=\bigcap_{\substack{(I,+)<(R,+)\\
 A\subseteq (I,+)}} I
\end{equation}
This clearly contains $a$. It is, in fact, the smallest ideal containing $a$. For Rings with unit, this is equivalent to the deffinition you have given.